# Switching number of columns for 'active'/'target' element (Jquery)

Tags: jquery

I have a function that attempts to switch the # of columns for a specific `<ul>` and it's children `<il>`. My issue is the `<ul>` I'm targeting is not distinct other than being a descendant of the element ".pft-directory" that initiates the function. Which leads me to my dilemma, I don't know how to isolate the active/target element since it's not unique. I imagine some form of ".target". or the use of "$this" but again I'm unsure of how to solve it this way.  The purpose is based on the count of "li.pft-file.ext-htm" determines the column size (anything over 1 should have 2 columns. And anything else has 1 column.

```
$(".pft-directory").click(function() {
    var liCol = 1   
    var count = $("li.pft-file.ext-htm").length;
    if ((liCol = 1) && (count > 1)) {
    $(".pft-directory > ul").css("columns", "2", "-webkit-columns", "2");
    liCol = 2;            
    } else {
        $(".pft-directory > ul").css("columns", "1", "-webkit-columns", "1");
        liCol = 1;
    }
});
```

This ("li.pft-file.ext-htm") is the 'element(s)' I'm trying to get a count for. However I only want to count these element(s) that are under the 'active' or 'target' element that initiated function (".pft-directory").

Code Updates: (Includes HTML)

```js
<!-- This function collapses the li under an open li-->
  <!-- Togles all 'Other' Top Level li elements on click-->
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var col = 2
    $(".pft-directory").click(function() {
      $(".pft-directory").toggle("fast");
      $(this).toggle("fast");
      if (col > 1) {
        $("ul.php-file-tree").css("columns", "1", "-webkit-columns", "1");
        col = 1;
      } else {
        $("ul.php-file-tree").css("columns", "2", "-webkit-columns", "2");
        col = 2;
      }
    });




    $(".pft-directory").click(function() {
      var liCol = 1
      var count = $("li.pft-file.ext-htm", this).length;
      if ((liCol = 1) && (count > 1)) {
        $(".pft-directory > ul", this).css("columns", "2", "-webkit-columns", "2");
        liCol = 2;
      } else {
        $(".pft-directory > ul", this).css("columns", "1", "-webkit-columns", "1");
        liCol = 1;
      }
    });


    $(".open").hover(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('initial-text', $this.text());
        $this.text("Click to return to previous page");
    });
  });
```

```html
<link href="styles/default/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<!-- Makes the file tree(s) expand/collapsae dynamically -->
<script src="php_file_tree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>File Tree </h1>
<h2>Browsing Training Videos...</h2>
<ul class="php-file-tree" style="-webkit-column-width: auto; -webkit-column-count: 1;">
  <li class="pft-directory" style="display: none;"><a href="#" class="closed">01 - System Overview and System Manager</a>
    <ul style="display: none;">
      <li class="pft-file ext-htm"><a href="http://www.URL/files/Training/01 - System Overview and System Manager/L201-TESTING+LENGTH+OF+VIDEO+TITLE+WOOOOO.htm">L201 TESTING LENGTH OF VIDEO TITLE WOOOOO</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pft-file ext-htm"><a href="http://www.URL/files/Training/01 - System Overview and System Manager/L202+-+Test.htm">L202   Test</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="pft-directory" style="display: none;"><a href="#">02 - Hardware</a>
    <ul style="display: none;">
      <li class="pft-file ext-htm"><a href="http://www.URL/files/Training/02 - Hardware/L201-Controller-Fimware-Update.htm">L201 Controller Fimware Update</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pft-file ext-htm"><a href="http://www.URL/files/Training/02 - Hardware/L203+-+Test.htm">L203   Test</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="pft-directory" style="display: none;"><a href="#">03 - Locations and Objects</a>
  </li>
  <li class="pft-directory" style="display: list-item;"><a href="#" class="open">04 - iPatch Synchronization</a>
    <ul style="display: block;">
      <li class="pft-file ext-htm"><a href="http://www.URL/files/Training/04 - iPatch Synchronization/Doc_1.htm">Doc_1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pft-file ext-htm"><a href="http://www.URL/files/Training/04 - iPatch Synchronization/Doc_2.htm">Doc_2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pft-file ext-htm"><a href="http://www.URL/files/Training/04 - iPatch Synchronization/Doc_3.htm">Doc_3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pft-file ext-htm"><a href="http://www.URL/files/Training/04 - iPatch Synchronization/Doc_4.htm">Doc_4</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pft-file ext-htm"><a href="http://www.URL/files/Training/04 - iPatch Synchronization/Doc_5.htm">Doc_5</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pft-file ext-htm"><a href="http://www.URL/files/Training/04 - iPatch Synchronization/Doc_6%29.htm">Doc_6)</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pft-file ext-htm"><a href="http://www.URL/files/Training/04 - iPatch Synchronization/Doc_7.htm">Doc_7</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pft-file ext-htm"><a href="http://www.URL/files/Training/04 - iPatch Synchronization/Doc_8.htm">Doc_8</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pft-file ext-htm"><a href="http://www.URL/files/Training/04 - iPatch Synchronization/Doc_9.htm">Doc_9</a>
      </li>
      <li class="pft-file ext-htm"><a href="http://www.URL/files/Training/04 - iPatch Synchronization/Doc_10.htm">Doc_10</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="pft-directory" style="display: none;"><a href="#">05 - SNMP and Device Discovery</a>
  </li>
  <li class="pft-directory" style="display: none;"><a href="#">06 - Cabling and OSP Cabling</a>
  </li>
  <li class="pft-directory" style="display: none;"><a href="#">07 - Patching</a>
  </li>
  <li class="pft-directory" style="display: none;"><a href="#">08 - Services and Deploy Server</a>
  </li>
  <li class="pft-directory" style="display: none;"><a href="#">09 - Event Notifications</a>
  </li>
  <li class="pft-directory" style="display: none;"><a href="#">10 - Reports</a>
  </li>
  <li class="pft-directory" style="display: none;"><a href="#">11 - Import Wizard</a>
  </li>
  <li class="pft-directory" style="display: none;"><a href="#">12 - Tools</a>
  </li>
</ul>This is a TEST
```

This resolved my issue:

```
  $(".pft-directory").click(function() {
    var liCol = 1   
    var count = $("li.pft-file.ext-htm",this).length;
    if ((liCol = 1) && (count > 1)) {
    $(".pft-directory > ul").css("columns", "2", "-webkit-columns", "2");
    liCol = 2;            
    } else {
        $(".pft-directory > ul").css("columns", "1", "-webkit-columns", "1");
        liCol = 1;
    }
});'
```

Comment: we would need to see a sample html structure, including multiples

Comment: Ok, I've reformatted your message to put the code you had into a code snippet.  How is it not working the way you want it to?  You click on "04 - iPatch Synchronization" and it turns it into 2 columns.  I did have to fix an issue with the last bit of your javascript (the .open stuff) as it looked like you removed the unhover portion of it and left a closing } which was throwing javascript errors, and breaking the entire page.

Comment: @Robert Mckee  - I was still having an issue where a <ul> had only one <il> but was still displaying with two columns. Updated what worked above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".pft-directory").click(function() {
    var liCol = 1   
    var count = $("li.pft-file.ext-htm",this).length;
    if ((liCol = 1) && (count > 1)) {
      $(".pft-directory > ul",this).css("columns", "2", "-webkit-columns", "2");
      liCol = 2;            
    } else {
        $(".pft-directory > ul",this).css("columns", "1", "-webkit-columns", "1");
        liCol = 1;
    }
});
```

Although you should consider using a class instead of inline css styles, like this:

```
$(".pft-directory").click(function() {
    var liCol = 1   
    var count = $("li.pft-file.ext-htm",this).length;
    $('.pft-directory > ul',this).removeClass('myclass');
    if ((liCol = 1) && (count > 1)) {
      $(".pft-directory > ul",this).addClass('myclass');
    }
});

.pft-directory > ul { -webkit-columns:1 ; columns:1 }
.pft-directory > ul.myclass { -webkit-columns:2; columns:2; }
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. Still having issues. I probably didn't explain well enough. I've updated my original post with the HTML. If you look at this element'<li class="pft-directory" style="display: list-item;">' I'm trying to count its children with class 'pft-file ext-htm'. If greater than one than the <ul>(parent) for those children should change the number of columns from 2 to 1